# How to select only items that have at least so many characters in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to pull comparative data.

For simplicity sake some fake data is below.

```
12red34
56red78
90blue23
45blue67
89yellow10
```

What I want is to pull only items with 3 sequential non defined items.

In this case, it would pull all of the items except 89yellow10 as no other item on the list contains 3 characters in a row that match it. 90blue23 and 45blue67 both contain "blue (or some combination of those letters)" and the same with the "red" items.

This is on a very large table and manually searching using a contain clause doesn't seem feasible.

Thank you.

Comment: If you really need to find only matches where there are 3 sequential characters you are not going to do it quickly.

Comment: Quickly in terms of how long it would take to run the code or quickly in terms of actually doing it?

Comment: Coding time is not a concern. Execution time is. And considering what you are asking it isn't going to be something that can be executed quickly. It could be any three characters in a string. That means you have to split your values into all the 3 characters strings and see if any other rows have that same pattern. There just isn't a way to make that run fast.

Comment: Honestly, the only 'practical' way I can see for this to be done is to shred your data into three character segments (seg char(3), recordID int), then delete the matched sequences and see what is left over. Also, does position in the string matter? That is, would `89yellow10` be matched by `32cow19` and `55blower11`?

Comment: One other question - does self-similarity count? That is, does `01harhar10` match itself, since the three character string 'har' is in there twice?

Comment: Where they are does matter, they should be sequential so 89yellow10 would not be matched by 32cow19 or 55blower11 as the characters in the string aren't sequential. "yel" would only be matched to "yel" and would not match "ley". 



As for characters matching within the same item, such as "harhar" being returned, I'd prefer if they didn't but, that would be the least of my issues.

Comment: This is not something that you will want to do on your database.  Rather, you will want to read all of the data into a client program and then implement this very complex filter there.. And it's not going to be very easy or fast there either, just way better than trying to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This will perform with the sample data, **however**, Laughing Vergil has completely valid points.

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,SomeString varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'12red34'),
(2,'56red78'),
(3,'90blue23'),
(4,'45blue67'),
(5,'89yellow10')


Declare @MatchLen int = 3
;with cte as (
      Select ID,B.*
      From  @YourTable A
      Cross Apply (
                    Select N,S=substring(A.SomeString,N,@MatchLen)
                    From (Select Top (Len(A.SomeString)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values) N
                   ) B 
      Where substring(A.SomeString,N,3) like Replicate('[A-Z]',@MatchLen)
)
Select A.*
      ,MinS = min(S)
      ,MaxS = max(S)
 From  @YourTable A
 Join ( 
        Select  S
         From   cte A
         Group  By S
         Having Count(*)>=2
      ) B 
 On  CharIndex(S,SomeString)>0  
 Group By ID,SomeString
 Order By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  SomeString  MinS    MaxS
1   12red34     red     red
2   56red78     red     red
3   90blue23    blu     lue
4   45blue67    blu     lue
```

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with CTE, could you offer guidance on how I could narrow the above down with a where clause? The above works but, it pulls a bunch of inactive items that I would like to exclude but, when I added a where clause it appears to just ignore it.

Comment: @SQLISHARD Updated the answer.  I didn't make the initial WHERE very clear.  Just remove the comment -- and add your where condition

Comment: You can add the where after the cte is defined...`SELECT ... FROM YourCTE WHERE...`